# java Strange WatchService

Tags: java, watchservice

My OS is Windows7.

I make directory like this

```
WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
Path rootPath = Paths.createDirectory(Paths.get("c:/foo"));
rootPath.register(watchService, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_CREATE);

Path depth1Child = Paths.createDirectory(Paths.get("c:/foo/depth1"));

WatchKey key = null;

//printed : ENTRY_CREATE c:/foo/depth1
while((key=watchService.poll()) != null) {
    for (WatchEvent e : key.pollEvents())
        System.out.println(e.kind()+" "+e.context());
    key.reset();
}

depth1Child.register(watchService, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_CREATE);
Path depth2Child = Paths.createDirectory(Paths.get("c:/foo/depth1/depth2"));

//printed : ENTRY_MODIFY c:/foo/depth1, ENTRY_CREATE c:/foo/depth1/depth2
while((key=watchService.poll()) != null) {
    for (WatchEvent e : key.pollEvents())
        System.out.println(e.kind()+" "+e.context());
    key.reset();
}
```

why diffent event after first depth directory creation and second path creation?

I register c:/foo path with ENTRY_MODIFY and ENTRY_CREATE, and c:/foo/depth1, c:/foo/depth2 either.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since "c:/foo" is registred for ENTRY_MODIFY and ENTRY_CREATE events, when you create "c:/foo/depth1", you get ENTRY_CREATE event.
Because ENTRY_MODIFY and ENTRY_CREATE events are registred for "c:/foo/depth1", when you create "c:/foo/depth1/depth2", you have modified "c:/foo/depth1", so you get:

- ENTRY_MODIFY for "c:/foo/depth1"
- ENTRY_CREATE for "c:/foo/depth1/depth2"